# glossary not appearing latex texmaker

Tags: glossaries, texmaker

I installed Miktex last version again and tried creating a glossary but it doesnt work nor texwork either texmaker... but it does work in overleaf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

this is the log I get in texmaker

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7380 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.3.28) 28 MAR 2020 21:49
entering extended mode
**./glosario.tex
(glosario.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks15
\inpenc@posthook=\toks16
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/glossaries/base\glossaries.sty"
Package: glossaries 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count175
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mfirstuc\mfirstuc.sty"
Package: mfirstuc 2017/11/14 v2.06 (NLCT)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count176
)
\@glsmfirst=\toks19
\@glsmrest=\toks20
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/textcase\textcase.sty"
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xfor\xfor.sty"
Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/datatool\datatool-base.sty"
Package: datatool-base 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks21
\ex@=\dimen135
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen136
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count177
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227.
\uproot@=\count178
\leftroot@=\count179
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389.
\classnum@=\count180
\DOTSCASE@=\count181
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box45
\strutbox@=\box46
\big@size=\dimen137
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734.
\macc@depth=\count182
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count183
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count184
\dspbrk@lvl=\count185
\tag@help=\toks22
\row@=\count186
\column@=\count187
\maxfields@=\count188
\andhelp@=\toks23
\eqnshift@=\dimen138
\alignsep@=\dimen139
\tagshift@=\dimen140
\tagwidth@=\dimen141
\totwidth@=\dimen142
\lineht@=\dimen143
\@envbody=\toks24
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks25
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2859.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2860.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/substr\substr.sty"
Package: substr 2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
\c@su@anzahl=\count189
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/datatool\datatool-fp.sty"
Package: datatool-fp 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\fp.sty"
Package: fp 1995/04/02
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\defpattern.sty"
Package: defpattern 1994/10/12
\actioncount=\count190
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\fp-basic.sty"
Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13
\FP@xs=\count191
\FP@xia=\count192
\FP@xib=\count193
\FP@xfa=\count194
\FP@xfb=\count195
\FP@rega=\count196
\FP@regb=\count197
\FP@regs=\count198
\FP@times=\count199
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\fp-addons.sty"
Package: fp-addons 1995/03/15
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\fp-snap.sty"
Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\fp-exp.sty"
Package: fp-exp 1995/04/03
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\fp-trigo.sty"
Package: fp-trigo 1995/04/14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\fp-pas.sty"
Package: fp-pas 1994/08/29
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\fp-random.sty"
Package: fp-random 1995/02/23
\FPseed=\count266
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\fp-eqn.sty"
Package: fp-eqn 1995/04/03
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\fp-upn.sty"
Package: fp-upn 1996/10/21
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fp\fp-eval.sty"
Package: fp-eval 1995/04/03
)))
\@dtl@toks=\toks26
\@dtl@tmpcount=\count267
\dtl@tmplength=\skip52
\dtl@sortresult=\count268
\@dtl@numgrpsepcount=\count269
\@dtl@datatype=\count270
\dtl@codeA=\count271
\dtl@codeB=\count272
\@dtl@foreach@level=\count273
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/glossaries/base\glossaries-compatible-3
07.sty"
Package: glossaries-compatible-307 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
)
\gls@level=\count274
\@gls@tmpb=\toks27
\gls@tmplen=\skip53
\glskeylisttok=\toks28
\glslabeltok=\toks29
\glsshorttok=\toks30
\glslongtok=\toks31
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\glossary-hypernav.sty
"
Package: glossary-hypernav 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\glossary-list.sty"
Package: glossary-list 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
\glslistdottedwidth=\skip54
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\glossary-long.sty"
Package: glossary-long 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\longtable.sty"
Package: longtable 2020/01/07 v4.13 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip55
\LTright=\skip56
\LTpre=\skip57
\LTpost=\skip58
\LTchunksize=\count275
\LTcapwidth=\dimen144
\LT@head=\box47
\LT@firsthead=\box48
\LT@foot=\box49
\LT@lastfoot=\box50
\LT@cols=\count276
\LT@rows=\count277
\c@LT@tables=\count278
\c@LT@chunks=\count279
\LT@p@ftn=\toks32
)
\glsdescwidth=\skip59
\glspagelistwidth=\skip60
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\glossary-super.sty"
Package: glossary-super 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/supertabular\supertabular.sty"
Package: supertabular 2020/02/02 v4.1g the supertabular environment
\c@tracingst=\count280
\ST@wd=\dimen145
\ST@rightskip=\skip61
\ST@leftskip=\skip62
\ST@parfillskip=\skip63
\ST@pageleft=\dimen146
\ST@headht=\dimen147
\ST@tailht=\dimen148
\ST@pagesofar=\dimen149
\ST@pboxht=\dimen150
\ST@lineht=\dimen151
\ST@prevht=\dimen152
\ST@toadd=\dimen153
\ST@dimen=\dimen154
\ST@pbox=\box51
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/glossaries/styles\glossary-tree.sty"
Package: glossary-tree 2020/03/19 v4.46 (NLCT)
\glstreeindent=\skip64
))
\glswrite=\write3
\glo@main@file=\write4
\openout4 = `glosario.glo'.
Package glossaries Info: Writing glossary file glosario.glo on input line 5.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def"
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count281
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
)
No file glosario.aux.
\openout1 = `glosario.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 24.
[1
\openout3 = `glosario.ist'.
{C:/Users/Emilio/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
No file glosario.gls.
[2
] (glosario.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
5103 strings out of 480932
76396 string characters out of 2909667
369895 words of memory out of 3000000
20912 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
536047 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
51i,4n,39p,991b,187s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mr10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on glosario.pdf (2 pages, 26536 bytes).
PDF statistics:
17 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the option [automake] to the package did create a glossary using MiKTeX and TeXStudio.

All I changed was the line loading the glossaries package to:

```
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}
```